# from gwt to phonegap

Tags: cordova, gwt, phonegap-build, mgwt

I heard about phonegap just a few days ago and I wanted to try and start by myself making an app in all platforms by writing with the gwt and phonegap together.

the thing is that I'm not sure I got the idea quite well. I know that I need to develop the web app with gwt and with the mgwt library, after that I need to open a new all-platforms-project with cordova, and install the android platform project.

now, lets say I started coding in gwt, and I compiled it, what do I do now? how do I get my java script code to my android project?

I am very new in this and I would glad if someone could help me and could give me an explanation for all the things I didn't got right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@liranahum,
from your writing I can tell you have some misconceptions about how Phonegap works.

I would suggest something other that [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/). While GWT *would work*, you would have an uphill battle on different aspects. I would suggest [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) - which seems to be the most popular.

If you want something more generic, then start with the [Phonegap Beginners Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/).

Lastly, you will want to not trip on some obvious things that many developers new to phonegap often find.

*Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap*
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md

Best of Luck,
Jesse